# Activerecord - Return all records with children for every date within an array of dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following tables:

```
class Contract
  has_many :working_days
end

Class WorkingDay
  belongs_to :contract
end
```

The `working_days` table has a `date` field.

I also have an array of dates, for example:

```
dates_array = [Date.today, Date.today + 1.week, Date.today + 2.weeks, Date.today + 3.weeks, Date.today + 4.weeks]
```

As fast as possible, and within one Activerecord or SQL query, how can I return all contracts that have a working day for *all* of the dates within the `dates` array?

I want this to be as fast as possible, so  I don't want to loop over the dates array and run multiple queries.

If it was possible to `map` an SQL query from the `dates_array` that could be run within an Activerecord query, that would be ok. Something like:

```
Contract.joins(:working_days).where(working_days: dates_array.map { |date| "('date=?','#{date}') #{'OR' unless date == dates_array.last}" }.join(''))
```

But this code doesn't work, and so far I haven't been able to come up with anything that does, apart from looping over the array of dates (too slow).

Within one query, does anyone know how I can return all contracts that have a working day for *all* of the dates within the dates array?

Thank you to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the contract records having working_days, where the working_days have exactly those dates that `dates_array` holds, where the total of working_days is exactly the same number of elements in `dates_array`, while grouping the contract rows by id:

```
Contract
  .joins(:working_days)
  .where(working_days: { date: dates_array })
  .group(:id)
  .having('COUNT(*) = ?', dates_array.size)
```